# How can I detect the CEFR level of a resource?

Tags: cefr

Suppose, I have an English text (poem book, storybook, novel, article, etc.) or an audio or a video in my hand. I want to use it in my lesson plan.

How can I detect the CEFR level of this English resource which I am planning to use?